# Calculating total BOM quantity in Presto SQL

Tags: python, sql, presto

I've been stuck with a requirement I have to calculate total bom qty based on the following sample data:

| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N | 1382 | 0007 | 22 |
| Y | 0007 | 0242 | 2 |
| Y | 0007 | 0242 | 2 |
| N | 0007 | 0005 | 2 |
| Y | 0007 | 0003 | 2 |
| Y | 0007 | 009D | 16 |
| N | 0005 | 0006 | 1 |
| Y | 0006 | 05R5 | 5 |

lowest_level here represents if part number is found in parent number. If 'N', then it is a parent number.
Also, note that the parent_number can appear in any order.

I need to calculate the total bom qty as follows: total bom_qty for parent * bom_qty. The challenge that I'm having is when both parent and part numbers are parent numbers e.g. 0007 and 0005. The expected total bom qty would be as follows:

| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty | total_bom_qty | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N | 1382 | 0007 | 22 | 22 | it is the starting point, so would just carry that value over for 0007 |
| Y | 0007 | 0242 | 2 | 44 | 22 * 2 |
| Y | 0007 | 0242 | 2 | 44 | 22 * 2 |
| N | 0007 | 0005 | 1 | 22 | 22 * 1 |
| Y | 0007 | 0003 | 2 | 44 | 22 * 2 |
| Y | 0007 | 009D | 16 | 352 | 22 * 16 |
| N | 0005 | 0006 | 1 | 22 | 22 (new value for 0005 calculated above) * 1 |
| Y | 0006 | 05R5 | 5 | 110 | 22 (new value for 0006 calculated above) * 5 |

The challenge that I am having is getting the updated values for a part number once it becomes a parent in the series. Currently, my results look as such:

| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty | total_bom_qty | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N | 0007 | 0005 | 1 | 22 | 22 * 1 |
| N | 0005 | 0006 | 1 | 1 | 1(0005 value in first row) * 1 |
| Y | 0006 | 05R5 | 5 | 5 | 1(0006 from above) * 5 |

What I have attempted at this point is doing a self join:

```
    SELECT
    c.lowest_level,
    c.parent_number,
    c.part_number,
    c.bom_qty,
    c.bom_qty * p.parent_bom AS total_bom_qty
FROM tbl AS c
INNER JOIN tbl AS p
    ON c.parent_number = p.part_number
```

This works up until I hit where both numbers are parents at some point e.g. 0007/0005, 0005/0006 combo

Is there a way to create a dynamic map in SQL where it would update the bom qty value for a part_number that is later a parent? I need a way to track updated values.

Not sure if that is the approach but am open to ideas on how to solve for this. Other related topics here suggest to use a recursive approach - Presto doesn't support this, so not sure how to implement it. I'd like to stick to SQL to solve this issue but if using Python helps am open to it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear why you have a lowest_level indicator.  This should be a typical hierarchical structure.  The parent_number is always a part_number (of the parent), unless NULL (or itself), which then represents the root component of a part tree.  Leaf nodes (lowest level parts) would be parts which have no corresponding rows with parent = this.

Comment: @JonArmstrong - I've only included the lowest_level column incase it helps identifying which rows have a parent-parent relationship. Can be disregarded if it isn't useful in the calculation. Essentially, the parent_number, part_number and bom_qty are needed to calculate the total bom

Comment: I used your first set of test data at the top.  It's a little different than your calculation example which follows.  That's why my results were a little different.  As far as recursion goes, if you don't have that, you'll either need to iterate procedurally or change the structure.  Changing the structure doesn't seem like the way to go, unless your data is rather static.

Comment: Is part_number intended to be unique?  You have part_number = '0242' more than once in the test data.

Comment: No, it can be the same - other columns in the table make the row unique. I've just included these rows in the data sample here as it was relevant for the calculation.

Comment: I've added to the answer to include a guide for iteratively generating the same result (and updating the bom table), without recursion, with a full working fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks much, @JonArmstrong - will test this non recursive approach in Presto. Appreciate your detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete test case which shows both the recursive logic and an example of executing each level iteratively, without recursion, and updating the bom table with the results.

[Working test case in another database](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bbdbf975ea5e4927d3837b5c3f6915b4)

To find the root nodes:

```
SELECT t1.lowest_level, t1.parent_number, t1.part_number, t1.bom_qty, t1.bom_qty AS total_bom, 1
  FROM      tbl AS t1
  LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2
    ON t2.part_number = t1.parent_number
 WHERE t2.part_number IS NULL
;
```

The result:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+---+
| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty | total_bom | 1 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+---+
| N            | 1382          | 0007        |      22 |        22 | 1 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+---+
```

To update the bom table for just the root nodes (first level):

```
UPDATE tbl
  JOIN (
          SELECT t1.lowest_level, t1.parent_number, t1.part_number, t1.bom_qty, t1.bom_qty AS total_bom, 1 AS n
            FROM      tbl AS t1
            LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2
              ON t2.part_number = t1.parent_number
           WHERE t2.part_number IS NULL           
       ) AS x
    ON x.part_number = tbl.part_number
   SET tbl.total_bom = x.total_bom
     , tbl.lev = x.n
;
```

The result:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl;

+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty | total_bom | lev  |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| N            | 1382          | 0007        |      22 |        22 |    1 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0242        |       2 |         0 |    0 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0242        |       2 |         0 |    0 |
| N            | 0007          | 0005        |       2 |         0 |    0 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0003        |       2 |         0 |    0 |
| Y            | 0007          | 009D        |      16 |         0 |    0 |
| N            | 0005          | 0006        |       1 |         0 |    0 |
| Y            | 0006          | 05R5        |       5 |         0 |    0 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

To update the next level of the hierarchy (parent level = 1):

```
UPDATE tbl
  JOIN (
          SELECT t1.lowest_level, t1.parent_number, t1.part_number, t1.bom_qty, t2.total_bom * t1.bom_qty AS total_bom, t2.lev+1 AS n
            FROM tbl  AS t1
            JOIN tbl  AS t2   
              ON t2.part_number = t1.parent_number
             AND t2.lev = 1 
       ) AS x
    ON x.part_number = tbl.part_number
   SET tbl.total_bom = x.total_bom
     , tbl.lev = x.n
;
```

The result:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl;

+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty | total_bom | lev  |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| N            | 1382          | 0007        |      22 |        22 |    1 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0242        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0242        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| N            | 0007          | 0005        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0003        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| Y            | 0007          | 009D        |      16 |       352 |    2 |
| N            | 0005          | 0006        |       1 |         0 |    0 |
| Y            | 0006          | 05R5        |       5 |         0 |    0 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

etc... until done.

Your database may not support this exact form directly. But it can be used as a guide of the logic.

With standard SQL, it looks something like this.

The first term of the `UNION` identifies all root parts, those with no parents.

The second term of the `UNION` iterates to each child part, recursively.

I've limited the depth to 6, just for testing.  Remove that or set the limit larger (for protection) as needed.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (lowest_level,parent_number,part_number,bom_qty,total_bom, n) AS (
         SELECT t1.lowest_level, t1.parent_number, t1.part_number, t1.bom_qty, t1.bom_qty, 1
           FROM      tbl AS t1
           LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2
             ON t2.part_number = t1.parent_number
          WHERE t2.part_number IS NULL           
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t1.lowest_level, t1.parent_number, t1.part_number, t1.bom_qty, t2.total_bom * t1.bom_qty, n+1
           FROM tbl  AS t1
           JOIN tree AS t2   
             ON t2.part_number = t1.parent_number
          WHERE n < 6
     )
SELECT *
  FROM tree
 ORDER BY n, part_number
;
```

The result:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| lowest_level | parent_number | part_number | bom_qty | total_bom | n    |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| N            | 1382          | 0007        |      22 |        22 |    1 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0003        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| N            | 0007          | 0005        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| Y            | 0007          | 009D        |      16 |       352 |    2 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0242        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| Y            | 0007          | 0242        |       2 |        44 |    2 |
| N            | 0005          | 0006        |       1 |        44 |    3 |
| Y            | 0006          | 05R5        |       5 |       220 |    4 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Armstrong - but recursive queries are not supported in Presto. I get the following error: (SYNTAX_ERROR) line 1:1: Recursive WITH queries are not supported

Also, why is this condition there: WHERE t2.part_number IS NULL

Comment: @Heather The `t2.part_number IS NULL` test is looking for t1 rows which have no matching t2 rows.  That's what is generated in a 'LEFT JOIN' for the missing cases.

Comment: Thanks @Jon - appreciate you taking the time to explain. Is there a way to use your query without the 'with recursive' Presto doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Heather Well, you could separate the terms of the `UNION` to iterate procedurally, in a stored procedure or in your application.  Start with the root parts (union term 1), and then iterate using the second union term until complete.  You could test the logic in a database which supports recursion to study the logic and then implement that iteratively in your app.